# GUI lag in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, lag, serial-communication, mscomm32

I have a program for carrying out serial communication. After sending a command, the program has to wait for a short while to receive the data. The data is received using ActiveX MsComm

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259393%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

The psuedocode looks something like this:

timer_tick

send data (node 1)

sleep(500) 'receives data for node 1 meanwhile

send data (node 2)

.
.
.

the problem is that sleep causes the GUI to lag. I've thought of a few alternatives

1) using an artificial counter in the timer to approximate 500ms before sending the next command but does not seem like a very good idea to me
2) using a thread instead of a timer? and setting it as a background thread

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=vs.71).aspx

3) making use of application.doevents?

I am not so familiar with option 2 or 3, therefore i am hesitant to introduce possibly complicating elements into my code. Can anybody advise of any alternative that's better suited for this problem or to start working towards option 2 or 3?

Comment: Why not simply do this in a worker thread?

Comment: Ok, i'm on it! Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using the COM component instead of .NET's [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ? Also, are you waiting to ensure you receive a response? Would it be OK to send the second command earlier if a response was received before 500ms?

Comment: Using .NET framework 1.1 ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the fact that your `timer` is running on the UI thread, so when you `sleep` in that sub-routine, you are sleeping the UI thread (hence the 'lag').

The <strike>best</strike> probably easiest to understand option is to add a `BackgroundWorker` control to your form and move your sending (and sleep) code into the worker `DoWork` routine, which will not block the UI thread.

Something like this:

```
Worker_DoWork
    send data (node 1)
    sleep(500) 'receives data for node 1 meanwhile
    send data (node 2)
End Sub
```

The use of `DoEvents` is **strongly** discouraged - there are very few reasons for using this in .NET

Comment: No reason to use a BackgroundWorker or Thread.Sleep either, when you can use Tasks and Task.Delay, avoiding blocking entirely.

Comment: Not what you think. It doesn't put anything to sleep. It starts a background timer, releases the original thread and picks up once an timer fires. It doesn't use nor put any thread to sleep.

Comment: Moreover, using Tasks with `Async/Await` is easier and simpler than BackgroundWorker in all cases. [Stephen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html) wrote an exhaustive series of posts displaying all alternatives to what BackgroundWorker does and the cases that it just can't cover, like reporting progress message.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs because you are putting the UI thread to sleep. In .NET 4.5, you can use `Task.Delay` to make your code execute only after a certain interval without blocking any thread, eg:

```
Dim port As New SerialPort
...
Public Async Sub SomeButton_Click()
    port.WriteLine("First")
    Await Task.Delay(500)
    port.WriteLine("Second")
    Await Task.Delay(300)
    port.WriteLine("Third")
End Sub
```

In this case the first `WriteLine` executes on the UI thread, a wait occurs in the background for 500ms (actually using a timer), then execution resumes on the original thread (the UI thread) and the second `WriteLine` occurs in the UI thread as well. Another 300 ms wait then the third WriteLine occurs in the UI thread as well.

The `Async\Await` combination allows you to write such code in a very clean manner, without involving other components like BackgroundWorker. It also allows you to do things that Background Worker just can't do, like execute multiple asynchronous calls. In such a case you would need to use multiple workers where now you just write one more statement

Note that the `Async Sub` syntax is used only for event handlers. In all other cases you should use `Async Function SomeFunction() As Task`.

If you want to run the entire sequence in a background thread, you can use `Task.Run`.

```
Public Async Sub SomeButton_Click()
    Task.Run(Async Function () 
            Await SendAndWait
        End Function)
End Sub

public Async Function SendAndWait As Task
    _port.WriteLine("First")
    Await Task.Delay(500)
    _port.WriteLine("Second")
    Await Task.Delay(300)
    _port.WriteLine("Third")
End Function
```

The real beauty of using Tasks, is that you can combine multiple asynchronous operations, something that's nearly impossible with BackgroundWorker. In this case, you can read data from a file or database asynchronously and send it to the serial port asynchronously, with very simple code:

```
public Async Function SendAndWait(filePath As String) As Task
    Dim line As String
      Using reader As New StreamReader(filePath)            
        For i=0 To 3 
            line=Await reader.ReadLineAsync() 
            _port.WriteLine(line)
            Await Task.Delay(500)                
        Next 
    End Using 
End Function
```

You can use the `async/await` keywords in .NET 4.0 code as well by adding the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) package to your project.

Comment: I am not using .NET 4.5, so i can only use BackgroundWorker. But thanks for alerting me to another alternative should i find myself working on the latest version of .NET someday :)

Comment: You can use all that in 4.0 as well. Task were added in .NET 4.0 while the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) package adds support for `async/await` to 4.0 for Visual Studio 2012+. Even if you use VS 2010, you can upgrade to the free Visual Studio 2013 Pro (sorry "Community") edition